# MySQL: UPDATE hundreds of rows at once?

Tags: mysql

Is it practical, or feasible, to UPDATE several hundreds of rows at once, or is there a technique for batch updating which I'm not aware of?

I have done a Google for this question, but it keeps throwing up results for combining multiple UPDATE queries into one.

As you can imagine, I'd rather not launch into this and cause problems with the server when a request comes through for 300+ update statements.

Comment: which kind of update? Something like `UPDATE test SET x=1` or a certain value per row?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor, I'll be using transactions in the framework, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @dognose, yes quite simple UPDATE queries.

Comment: I mean within the context of a transaction all updates *happen* at once

Comment: @JuniorCompressor, I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to know whether it would execute at one, which is why I'm asking: is there some technique to batch execute UPDATE queries?

Comment: I think you should make it clear. What problem are you trying to avoid? What are your concerns?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor as stated in the opening post: as you can imagine, I'd rather not launch into this and cause problems with the server when a request comes through for 300+ update statements.

Answer (score 1):

300 update statements should not be a problem.  You just use `update`:

```
update table t
    set . . .
    where . . .
```

This *could* be a problem if you had very complex triggers on the table.

Typically, you need to start worrying about updates when the numbers are in the tens of thousands.  Then the overhead of the logging and the time spent locking the table can have an impact on performance.

Comment: Gordon, thank you. I'll have to jump in and give it a go, to see what happens. But, if as you suggest, the low hundreds is viable, then I shouldn't (and I hope not to) have any problems.

Comment: @WayneSmallman . . . I should also add that if you have very high transaction volumes, then the update could slow down the system for perhaps a few seconds, which could cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

300+ is nothing, We update around 80k records in one of our synchronization jobs and it is basically done via join like this

```
UPDATE table_1
                INNER JOIN table_2 ON (table_1.DnameId = table_2.DNDOMAIN_ID)
                SET 
                table_1.Label = table_2.DOMAIN_LABEL,
                table_1.Extension = table_2.DOMAIN_EXTENSION
```

In your case,

```
update table_name set column='value'
```

would run smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

300 statements might not look a problem, but if you have strict SLAs, you should look for optimizing the solution. Since there is no clear information available as what is the nature of execution (is it batch job? online request? or anything else), I will recommend you consider following approaches before you implement the logic.

1. Calling 300+ statements inside one transaction unit is better than having transaction per query. If the nature of the requirement doesn't require Isolated transaction for every query, I will suggest you should better have one transaction for all. But remember there is one catch, if one of the record fails, all the data updated till that point will also get rolled back.
2. Use native updater as much as possible when there is bulk data operations are involved and data can be made available using files, for e.g. [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)
3. Check if the table has any triggers, which comes into action as soon as data is updated. This will have significant impact on the query execution.